# HiveError: This object is not currently in a box. When trying to save a hive object in a list in another hive object

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm working on an app with flutter and hive local nosql database.

I made a hive object that contains a list of another hive object.

This is the first object:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class FirstObject extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String string;

  @HiveField(1)
  late DateTime dateTime;

  @HiveField(2)
  late List<SecondObject> secondObject = [];
}
```

This is the second object:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class SecondObject extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String something;

  @HiveField(1)
  bool boolean = false;

  @HiveField(2)
  late DateTime? date;
}
```

I generated adapters for both objects and registered them but I generated only one box for the first object that contains the second object.

Then a list variable representing the list in the first object and made a listview builder that has list tiles with a checkbox that updates the boolean in the second object and then saves it.

But when I test it it gives me an error saying:

```
The following HiveError was thrown while handling a gesture:
This object is currently not in a box.
```

I tried some solutions like making another box for the second object and declaring a variable in the second object containing the first object that is belongs to. But those solutions gave me other errors.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because:
Very long Q - than the same author answer himself (He notice new fact that solves his problem) - no value for this Q for other users

Answer (score -2):

Now I realized that I can save the first container object instead of just the second object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have exact problem to this thread, but this answer is unclear.